# How to run browser.js from babel in Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, babeljs, nashorn

I'm trying to run browser.js in Nashorn, to use babel.transform in the library for some Isomorphic Webapp.

1. run `npm i babel-core` in my project
2. Here is the source of BabelTransformer class:

   ```
   public BabelTransformer() throws ScriptException, IOException{  
   try
       {
           ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
           ScriptEngine nashorn = mgr.getEngineByName("nashorn");
           nashorn.eval("var process = {env:{}}"); // node-modules expect that
           nashorn.eval("var global = this;"); // react expects that
           nashorn.eval(getScript("com/facebook/babel/jvm-npm.js"));
           nashorn.eval(getScript("com/facebook/babel/node_modules/babel-core/browser.min.js")); //The line 43
           babel = (ScriptObjectMirror)nashorn.eval("babel");
           invocable = (Invocable) nashorn;
       }
       catch(ScriptException | IOException e)
       {
           throw new Error(e); //this is line 49
       }
   }
   ```

But I've got an error, that I can't diagnose/resolve:

```
Testcase: testTransformOnHtmlElement(com.facebook.babel.BabelTransformerTest):  Caused an ERROR
javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:1 Expected ; but found error

 ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 1
java.lang.Error: javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:1 Expected ; but found error

 ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 1
    at com.facebook.babel.BabelTransformer.<init>(BabelTransformer.java:49)
    at com.facebook.babel.BabelTransformerTest.setUp(BabelTransformerTest.java:16)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:1:1 Expected ; but found error

 ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:534)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:521)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:399)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at com.facebook.babel.BabelTransformer.<init>(BabelTransformer.java:43)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:1:1 Expected ; but found error

 ^
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:292)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:277)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expectDontAdvance(AbstractParser.java:348)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expect(AbstractParser.java:335)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.endOfLine(Parser.java:3369)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expressionStatement(Parser.java:1162)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:969)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:775)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.program(Parser.java:711)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:284)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:250)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1281)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1248)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:629)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:532)
```

What should I do to run browser.js in Nashorn?

Comment: Would it have a problem with the file starting with a BOM? Can you try the `browser.js` from `babel-core@<5.8.20`?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll give it a try;

Comment: Sorry, that's all I could think of :(

Comment: Thank's anyway: I found a strange behavior, when I slightly modify the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972054/empty-range-in-char-class-in-eval-when-trying-to-run-browser-js-on-nashorn